# Update SQL Server Using SQL Command Object that has Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sqlcommandbuilder

I am trying to get my head around data access using VB.NET 2010.

I am slowly building a dummy application of contacts. I have it working with an SQL command object to handle the ADD, UPDATE and DELETE but it inly supports single table queries. I know I have to set the commands manually if there is a join but not sure how.

Here is my current code that retrieves the data from a Contact table and and a Contact Type Table

```
    Private Sub frmContacts_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        bloading = True 'variable to denote form is loading
        ModMain.InitaliseDBConnection() ' open connection to database using public connection "cn"

        sqlAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sSqlContactsJoined, cn)
        sqlAdapter.Fill(datblContacts) 'fill datatable with result of sSqlContactsJoined
        CmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sqlAdapter) 'generate the ADD, UPDATE and DELETE statements

        dgrdContacts.DataSource = datblContacts
        FormatGrid() 'Set the headers and hide ID columns on datagrid
        FillComboBox() 'fill combobox with ContactTypes
        bloading = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

The value of sSqlContactsJoined is :

```
Dim sSqlContactsJoined As String = "SELECT dbo.tblContacts.*, dbo.tblContactType.ContactType FROM " _
                                & " dbo.tblContacts INNER JOIN dbo.tblContactType ON dbo.tblContacts.ContactTypeID = dbo.tblContactType.ContactTypeID"
```

any pointers to a tutorial that may show me  how to manually enter the ADD UPDATE & DELETE statements for the CommandBulder?

Comment: Look up `SqlCommand` on MSDN.

Comment: From MSDN: `SqlcommandBuilder Automatically generates single-table commands ...`

Answer (score 2):

If your query includes a join then you don't use a command builder at all.  You have to create `SqlCommand` objects and assign them to the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` properties of the data adapter explicitly, e.g.

```
Private connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
Private adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Name, Quantity, Unit FROM StockItem", _
                                      connection)
Private table As New DataTable

Private Sub InitialiseDataAdapter()
    Dim delete As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM StockItem WHERE ID = @ID", Me.connection)
    Dim insert As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO StockItem (Name, Quantity, Unit) VALUES (@Name, @Quantity, @Unit)", Me.connection)
    Dim update As New SqlCommand("UPDATE StockItem SET Name = @Name, Quantity = @Quantity, Unit = @Unit WHERE ID = @ID", Me.connection)

    delete.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "ID")

    insert.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "Name")
    insert.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Float, 8, "Quantity")
    insert.Parameters.Add("@Unit", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, "Unit")

    update.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "Name")
    update.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Float, 8, "Quantity")
    update.Parameters.Add("@Unit", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, "Unit")
    update.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "ID")

    Me.adapter.DeleteCommand = delete
    Me.adapter.InsertCommand = insert
    Me.adapter.UpdateCommand = update

    Me.adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
End Sub

Private Sub GetData()
    'Retrieve the data.'
    Me.adapter.Fill(Me.table)

    'The table can be used here to display and edit the data.'
    'That will most likely involve data-binding but that is not a data access issue.'
End Sub

Private Sub SaveData()
    'Save the changes.'
    Me.adapter.Update(Me.table)
End Sub
```